# ¿Qué significa 'const' cuando declaras una método en una clase C++?

Tags: c++

¿Alguien me puede decir qué significa `const` en estos ejemplos?

```
int PosicionX() const; //Método que devuelve la posición X de Coordenada

Coordenada(const Coordenada &c); //Constructor de copia
```

Tanto el constructor como el método se encuentran en la parte `public` de `class Coordenada`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int PosicionX() const;
```

Este ejemplo, tal cual está, no es legal en C++. Otra cosa es que este método sea una función miembro de una clase:

```
class Coordenada
{
    int PosicionX() const;
};
```

En este caso, ese `const` significa que la función **no va a modificar** las variables miembro del objeto o, lo que es lo mismo, que no va a modificar el estado del objeto. Un ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
struct Coordenada
{
    int var;

    // ok, no modifica var
    int PosicionX() const
    { return var; } 

    // ERROR: var NO puede ser modificada
    int PosicionX2() const
    {
      var++;
      return var;
    }

    // Todo OK, la funcion no es const
    int PosicionX3() 
    {
      var++;
      return var;
    } 
};
```

La utilidad de este modificador la encontramos cuando tratamos con el segundo caso que has puesto:

```
Coordenada(const Coordenada &c);
```

En este caso, el modificador `const` está afectando a la referencia `c`, la cual **no puede** ser modificada dentro de la función (en este caso la función es un constructor copia). Otro ejemplo:

```
struct Coordenada
{
  int var;
};

// ok, c NO es const
void func1(Coordenada & c)
{ c.var = 5; }

// ERROR: c es const
void func2(Coordenada const& c) // Equivalente a 'const Coordenada &'
{ c.var = 5; }
```

Pues bien, sucede que cuando un objeto o referencia es constante, únicamente podremos llamar a métodos y funciones miembro del objeto que sean constantes:

```
void func1(Coordenada const& c)
{
  std::cout << c.PosicionX(); // OK, PosicionX es constante
  std::cout << c.PosicionX3(); // ERROR, PosicionX3 NO es constante
}
```

De hecho, nos podemos encontrar con dos funciones que se llamen exactamente igual solo que una incluye el modificador `const` y la otra no. Lo que sucederá aquí es que la función *no constante* será la utilizada por defecto ya que la función constante únicamente será llamada cuando estemos trabajando con un objeto constante:

```
struct POO
{
  int func()
  { return 1; }

  int func() const
  { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
  POO p;
  std::cout << p.func() << '\n'; // Imprime 1

  POO const& ref = p;
  std::cout << ref.func() << '\n'; // Imprime 2
}
```